# Counting rows of columns that does not exist

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count the rows of columns. While doing this i faced this problem

This is the data i have for example

I have 2 columns **ID** and **ANSWERS**
The values for column ID is A{yes,yes,no,no,maybe,maybe}
The values for column ANSWERS is B{yes,yes,no}

I'm trying to filter the answers where by i only want to count the value of "maybe". So the final answer i would want to get is

Column A{2] - There are 2 values of "maybe" in column A
Column B{0} - There are 0 values of "maybe" in column B

I used this query

```
select id, answers, count(*) as count from my_database
where answers = 'maybe' 
group by id, answers
```

This query only give me the count of "maybe" that EXISTED in the table's column.

I hope you guys can understand my explanation. Thank you!

Comment: can you create an [*SQL Fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/) data and show us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If individual column column values have repeating words, you can't apply `count` on them.
Instead you can calculate the number of occurrences of a specific pattern in the column value of a single row.

***Example***:

```
mysql> set @mb='A{yes,yes,no,no,maybe,maybe}';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @mb,
    ->    @len1:=length( @mb ) len1,
    ->    @rp1:=replace( @mb, 'maybe', '' ) rp1,
    ->    @len2:=length( @rp1 ) len2,
    ->    @dif:=( @len1 - @len2 ) dif,
    ->    @len3:=length( 'maybe' ) len3,
    ->    @cnt:=cast( @dif/@len3 as decimal ) cnt;
+------------------------------+------+--------------------+------+------+------+------+
| @mb                          | len1 | rp1                | len2 | dif  | len3 | cnt  |
+------------------------------+------+--------------------+------+------+------+------+
| A{yes,yes,no,no,maybe,maybe} |   28 | A{yes,yes,no,no,,} |   18 |   10 |    5 |    2 |
+------------------------------+------+--------------------+------+------+------+------+
```

On your table data following query may work.

```
select 
  id, answers, 
  cast( ( length(ID) - length( replace( ID, 'maybe', '' ) ) )
        / length('maybe')
        as decimal ) cnt 
from my_database
where answers = 'maybe'
```

And if you still want to `count` of a specific pattern per `ID` then use `group by` on the above solution.

```
select id, answers, sum(cnt) as total_count
from (
  select 
    id, answers, 
    cast( ( length(ID) - length( replace( ID, 'maybe', '' ) ) )
          / length('maybe')
          as decimal ) cnt 
  from my_database
  where answers = 'maybe' 
) tmp
group by id, answers
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, answers, count(*) as count from my_database
where answers = 'maybe' 
group by answers, id;
```

Comment: hey im trying to display the count of value "maybe" that does exist in the column. If there isn't, i wanna display maybe = 0